Why am I receiving this error upon sending HTTP request to this endpoint? Using Spring Boot
Hello I'm new to backend and Spring Boot here. I am using this as my backend for my Task Management Personal Project. I have omitted the entity, repository, service, and controller classes for brevity. They can be found here at my open source repo.
Essentially, a User can have multiple Project, A Project can have multiple Task. A Project can only have one User. A Task can only have one Project.
I was testing my endpoints and discovered an issue with my logic when calling this endpoint
POST localhost:8080/projects with a body of
    {
       "name": "Sample Project Name",
       "description": "sample description",
       "projectOwnerId": "4"
    }

This is the full error message minus the full trace:
{
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "trace": "org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute statement [Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value] [insert into projects (description,name,project_owner_id) values (?,?,?)]\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:341)\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.",
    "message": "could not execute statement [Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value] [insert into projects (description,name,project_owner_id) values (?,?,?)]",
    "path": "/projects"
}

To recreate:

Start Spring and then send POST localhost:8080/users with body

{
       "name": "James Sawyer",
       "email": "James.Say@email.com"
}


POST localhost:8080/projects

    {
       "name": "Sample Project Name",
       "description": "sample description",
       "projectOwnerId": "4"
    }

I have tried to play around with some annotations but I am completely unfamiliar with some of these backend concepts and would appreciate guidance. Thanks!

What do you think "Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value" means?

Your Project once had a mandatory field user: (from your git log):
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
private User user;

Now it's the projectOwner, you forgot to remove the user_id field in the database...
P.S. autoddl update only adds new columns, won't delete columns
P.P.S. for migration of data, removing fields etc. you have to include a db migration tool, there are lots of it...

Thank you for your time, yeah, that clears it up. I was having docker run a SQL server for me but I'm still fresh to docker as well and couldn't connect and see everything that was going on with the tables generated by Spring. I got rid of the docker container and am running SQL on my local machine and connected to that and it is working fine, that error is gone, after having set spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop in application.properties.
